# CSS Create Column Layout with Divs

Tags: css, height, width

All,
What I would like is to have a two column layout with a container div. The column on the left can be a fixed length and that would be ok. The column then to the right of that would then need to fill out the rest of the container div. Another issue I'm having is that the column to the right can have more data then the column on the left. How can I make the background or border of the left column be dynamic so that it is always the same height as the right column? Thanks for any advice you may have on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good article, he uses three columns but principals the same http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks  hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

you can do this using CSS, just give the width of the two divs in percentage like this:

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="leftCol"></div>
  <div class="rightCol"></div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.leftCol{
 float:left;
 width:20%;
}
.rightCol{
 float:left;
 width: 80%;
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: This css won't work. You need to float the divs + he needs the leftCol to be fixed width, also main already has a width of 100% since it's a block element and does not need a 100% declaration. And he needs equal height columns.

Comment: @easwee:  Thank you for your comment, I edited my answer. Though I am agree with you, my example won't fix the fixed width for the left div... the best approach would be in JavaScript

Comment: not really - can be done with pure css - see SGB answer which is the typical approach to this problem.